# Move/shift values in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming an example of a data frame **df**:

```
    A
0   4.3
1   75
2   8.5
3   4.0
4   98
```

I would need to move each value from column `A` to each column - one value per column:

- starting from second value: move to second column `B`,
- third value to third column `C`,
- and so on...

**Desired output:**

```
    A     B    C   D   E
0   4.3  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN   75  NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN  NaN  8.5 NaN NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN 4.0 NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN Nan  98
```

One idea was to copy each value to second column and then erase it in previous column or to `shift` value from one column to another but I'm not sure how to apply this...

**MWE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)), columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
df.iloc[:,1:] =np.nan

df.iloc[[1],[1]] = df.iloc[[1],[0]]
df.iloc[[1],[1]] = df.iloc[[1],[0]].shift(1,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [76]: import string

In [77]: r = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(len(df)), 
                          columns=list(string.ascii_uppercase[:len(df)])) \
               .replace(0, np.nan) * df.A.values

In [78]: r
Out[78]:
     A     B    C    D     E
0  4.3   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  NaN  75.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN  8.5  NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN  NaN  4.0   NaN
4  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  98.0
```

or better:

```
In [11]: r = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=list(string.ascii_uppercase[:len(df)]))

In [12]: np.fill_diagonal(r.values, df.A)

In [13]: r
Out[13]:
     A    B    C    D    E
0  4.3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN   75  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  8.5  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN    4  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   98
```

**UPDATE:**

> how to "move" single value

we can use [Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) method.

move horizontally:

```
In [94]: r.loc[1] = r.loc[1].shift(3)

In [95]: r
Out[95]:
     A   B    C    D     E
0  4.3 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  75.0
2  NaN NaN  8.5  NaN   NaN
3  NaN NaN  NaN  4.0   NaN
4  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  98.0
```

move vertically:

```
In [96]: r.loc[:, 'D'] = r.loc[:, 'D'].shift(-2)

In [97]: r
Out[97]:
     A   B    C    D     E
0  4.3 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  NaN NaN  NaN  4.0  75.0
2  NaN NaN  8.5  NaN   NaN
3  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
4  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  98.0
```

**NOTE:** `shift` will shift the **whole** row/column, but as soon as we have only one value in each row/column this will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you  know how to "move" values from column A to any column and any row - not diagonally?

Comment: @Michal, could you make a reproducible example?

Comment: For example to move value 75 to column D or 8.5 to column E. Or even to move 8.5 to the second row, column E.

Comment: @Michal, do you want to move them always horizontally? Do you want to move single values or to do it in a vectorized way?

Comment: I would like to move single value horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4.3, 75, 8.5, 4.0, 98]})
>>> df
      A
0   4.3
1  75.0
2   8.5
3   4.0
4  98.0


>>> diag_df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df.A), index=df.index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
>>> diag_df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
>>> diag_df
     A     B    C    D     E
0  4.3   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  NaN  75.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN  8.5  NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN  NaN  4.0   NaN
4  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  98.0
```

Keep in mind that if you have `0` along the diagonal then it will be replaced with `NaN` if you use the `replace` method this way.

Comment: what will happen to `0` values if they will be in the original `df` ? ;)

Comment: @MaxU Thanks. My solution to this is too close to your answer to change. I'll make a note.